# How can I select multiple dates in the same input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, input

I need to manage the dates when 'courses' are available.
I have an easy input data as follows:

```
 <input type="date" name="data" id="data">
```

How can I select multiple dates at the same time in the same input.

I could do with a start and end date but i want more specificity.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to use a button that saves dates to an array before saving... Something like this maybe?

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const sel = document.querySelector("select");
  const d = document.querySelector("#date").value;
  
  if (d === null || d === undefined)
  {
    alert("Select a date first.");
  }
  else
  {
    sel.innerHTML += `<option value="${d}">${d}</option>`;
  }
});

// Later on, post the option values from the select list to your backend:

document.querySelector("#finish").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var dates = [];
  for (let o of document.querySelectorAll("#dates option"))
  {
    dates.push(o.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Select dates</p>
  <input type="date" id="date" />

  <button>Add Date</button>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:20px;">
  <select name="dates" id="dates" size="5">
  </select>
</div>

<button id="finish">Finish</button>
```

I've included code on how to get the items from the select list options, but from there you'll have to handle the data in whatever way you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what sort of data you're describing or refering to with 'more specificity than with a start and end date'.

If you simply want to be able to submit a certain quantity of specific days/dates on which it should be available then you could use an array.

```
Date 1. <input type="date" name="data[]"><br>
Date 2. <input type="date" name="data[]"><br>
Date 3. <input type="date" name="data[]"><br>
Date 4. <input type="date" name="data[]"><br>
```

or incase you want multiple dateranges,

```
Dates 1. <input type="date" name="data_range_from[]"> to <input type="date" name="data_range_to[]"><br>
Dates 2. <input type="date" name="data_range_from[]"> to <input type="date" name="data_range_to[]"><br>
Dates 3. <input type="date" name="data_range_from[]"> to <input type="date" name="data_range_to[]"><br>
```

In either case, the server will receive an array of string entries, instead of a single string.

*do note that your `id="data"` is removed in all examples, as it would no longer be unique. You'd want to use a class instead.*